# Cannot return reference to temporary value with RwLock and iterators

Tags: rust, reference, iterator

I haven't found an answer to this in other questions.

I have reduced my problem to the following:

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;

pub fn main() {
    iter_lock().for_each(|v| {
        println!("{}", v);
    });
}

fn get_lock<'a>() -> &'a RwLock<Vec<u32>> {
    static mut lock: RwLock<Vec<u32>> = RwLock::new(Vec::new());
    unsafe { &lock }
}

fn iter_lock<'a>() -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'a u32> {
    get_lock().read().unwrap().iter()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87b5a780f3d268540988587dc8a158fd)

The code above will not compile and give the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     get_lock().read().unwrap().iter()
   |     --------------------------^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     returns a reference to data owned by the current function
   |     temporary value created here
   |
   = help: use `.collect()` to allocate the iterator
```

- Note that the static mut is not necessary in the code above, but I need it because I need to define a variable inside of an impl block.
- I need to return an iterator, not a Vec because I am trying to avoid any allocations, and this function will always be used to iterate.

How can I solve this issue? I'm not afraid of using unsafe code, so unsafe suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: In addition to what @SvenMarnach said (he at least used to have a comment above!), think about what you want: I believe you want your iterator to hold onto the result of the `read()` call, and keep that `RwLockReadGuard` alive for as long as the iterator is alive for.  If so, I think that would be a new struct to return, that would move the `RwLockReadGuard` into itself, and act as the iterator you want.  Which isn't what `.iter()` returns.

Comment: I acutally got confused by the use of a mutable static here. Your function `get_lock()` is actually sound, but it's a bit weird. First, there's no point in using a lifetime parameter `'a`. You should return a reference with `'static` lifetime instead. And second, there is no point in using a mutable static, since you never mutate it. Once you remove the `mut` qualifier, you don't need `unsafe` anymore. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e8987360cfc2b68e750fc9089658967))

Comment: @KevinAnderson Ah, haven't thought of that. That makes a lot of sense

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right, the static mut is not needed in this example. But in the original version I do mutate data behind the RwLock. Wasn't sure on whether to use `'a` or `'static` so thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Jomy Even if you mutate data behind the lock, the lock itself still doesn't need to be `mut`. That's kind of the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```rust
use std::sync::{RwLock, RwLockReadGuard};

pub fn main() {
    let data = Data::new(&[1, 2, 3]);

    data.iter().for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}


struct Data {
    inner: RwLock<Vec<u32>>,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(vec: &[u32]) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: RwLock::new(vec.to_vec()),
        }
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_> {
        let d = self.inner.read().unwrap();
        Iter::new(d)
    }
}

struct Iter<'a> {
    inner: RwLockReadGuard<'a, Vec<u32>>,
    current_index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iter<'a> {
    pub fn new(inner: RwLockReadGuard<'a, Vec<u32>>) -> Iter<'a> {
        Self {
            inner,
            current_index: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Iter<'_> {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.current_index >= self.inner.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let item = &self.inner[self.current_index];
        self.current_index += 1;
        Some(*item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the lock in a struct solves it indeed

Comment: Not meaning to put you down, but how is `Data` any better than just the raw `RwLock` itself?  Your `iterator` method on it is just calling `read()` and `unwrap()` in one step instead of two, with more boilerplate.  Your line in `main` would be literally the same, except `iterator()` replaced with `.read().unwrap()`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinAnderson updated example